# explain clojure dependencies slash syntax in project.clj?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure namespaces, I use slash to separate a namespace or namespace alias from a symbol in that namespace, as in

```
(ns whatever (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics]))
(clojure.math.combinatorics/subsets [42 43 44])
```

However, I just realized, looking at a `project.clj`, that slashes seem to mean something completely different in the dependencies section, as in

```
(defproject whatever "1.0.0"
  :description (str "yeah sure yubetcha")
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure            "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.3"]])
```

I don't usually have problems with dependencies: I just mindlessly scrape them from documentation and they get magically downloaded by `Leiningen` from `clojars.org` or the like. But I just realized that I don't understand the slash syntax here and would be grateful for a clarification, specifically if the usage is completely orthogonal to the usage of slash with namespaces or whether there is something more subtle going on.

Answer (score 2):

The slashes in clojure code are for separating the namespace from the function name in the namespace. The slashes in project.clj are part of the name of the project (by convention organization/product) as used by maven.

A / is a valid element of a symbol - for example try `'this/is/not/a/namespace` in the repl - it returns a symbol with a bunch of constituent slashes in it. The entire `(defproject ...)` form is inside an implicit syntax-quote (`), meaning you can have arbitrary names and they get treated as symbols (also you can use ~ to unquote and insert arbitrary code into project.clj, but this is usually a code smell).